# Copying datagrid column into an array?

Tags: c#, sql, datagrid

I'm Filling a datagrid from a dataset, with information retrieved from a database.
What i would like to do is take all the values from a particular column and put them into an array.

So for example a table named Ages, stored in a datagrid:

```
Ages
16
18
20
24
```

What i would like to is take the values out of the datagrid, without having to select them from the datagrid. Is this possible, can anyone send on a link or help on my problem, greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to grab all the values from the dataset that you used to populate the grid with:

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    List<object> myListArray = new List<object>();

    foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        myListArray.Add(dr["MyColumnName"]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you could select the named property from all the items from the datagrids datasource into an enumeration with link and put the result into an array. Something like this:

```
(from DataRow row in datagrid.datasource as DataTable select row[columnName]).ToArray()
```